# Connecting 2 table using another 2 table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, postgresql-9.6, php-7.1

I'm new to Laravel relations, and recently I faced a problem that I really don't know how to solve. I have 2 table that I want to link together. But there is 2 another inbetween table that I need to use.

[image: The challange in image]

I have these 4 models. I can not change the structure very much. Adding a few field maximum. I am done so far:

**Component.php**

```
namespace App\Models\Entity;

class Component extends Model
{
    public function xs() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ComponentX::class);
    }

    public function ys()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ComponentX::class);
    }

    public function foos() 
    {
        // ???
    }
}
```

I need to get foo models which belongs to a certain component (through component_x and component_y).

I know I can simply add "component_id" field to foo table.

But... is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Use foreign key reference available in laravel and define relationship among tables

Comment: Seems to me that the tables could be refined (ex: component_x and component_y seem similar from the image provided)

Comment: @Sagar: I didn't write that: I do not have migration files but there are foreign keys.

Comment: @ka_lin: Unfortunatelly the component_x and component_y table has different columns. The image I provided is a rough - and bad - example. And I'm not able to do that much change.

Comment: what kind of query u want to use when u linked them together